# How can I write a Python code with openCV that detects and counts the bones of hand?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, hough-transform

I am trying to write a python code with openCV to detect and count the bones of hand, and then find the area of detected bones.Same program should also apply for both hands, hand with a 6 finger, or images that also include shapes(like rectange or circle) in the background. Note that we can only use openCV or similar libraries, not libraries like tensorflow or keras for deep learning.

Here is an example images:

2 Hand Bones:
[image]

One hand but 6 fingers:
[image]

Here is my progress:

```
image = cv2.imread('Testbild3.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
```

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11),2)
plt.imshow(blur, cmap='gray')
```

```
img = image.copy()

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur ,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,40,
                            param1=40,param2=20,minRadius=16,maxRadius=82)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Here is the result I am getting:

[image: results]

I was expecting good circles around the bones so that I can count the bones and find their areas.

What can I do differently?

Comment: Did you check out mediapipie?
It might help here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doDUihpj6ro&t=5925s check this out.

Comment: yeah, I tried it, but it didn't work since I have x-ray images, and hands with six fingers.

Comment: You mention count the number of bones. are there cases where fingers have less or more than the expected number of bones? otherwise number of bones will just be `num_fingers*bones_per_finger`. Otherwise I'll do the following approach: Separate ech finger from the background, so you can process each finger separately. Now you know how each bone more o less looks like and where to find it. you can run segmentation and feature matching

Comment: There are no circles in those images, Hough is quite irrelevant.

Comment: I could not myself count the bones reliably as some gaps are dubious. For the carpus, this is just impossible.